# .net Встроенный веб сервер в приложении

Tags: c#, .net, веб-программирование

Требуется обрабатывать запросы из сети не сторонним веб-сервером, а десктопным приложением которые будут отправлять клиенты.
Проблемы с сервером то и нет, потому как в .Net есть `HttpListener` и `HttpServer`, с их помощью и сделан простой http - сервер по примеру [Создание веб-сервера](http://csharpprogramming.ru/web/kak-sozdat-veb-server-s-pomoshhyu-klassa-httplistener).

Но, проблема в том, что пока сервер слушает подключения, остальное приложение не грузится и это понятно, он же слушает в бесконечном цикле, далее цикла код не исполняется.

Вопрос - каким образом реализовать работу http-сервера так, что бы десктопное приложение не теряло функциональность? Может быть есть готовый встраиваемый web-сервер?

Comment: можно например запускать в отдельном потоке

Comment: Попробую, спасибо)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Запускайте сервер в отдельном потоке

```
Thread ServerThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(StartServer));
```